# Define HTML element color based on a Enum value with MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have a question category enum in my MVC project:

```
public enum QuestionCategory
{
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Category_Overall_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    Overall = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Category_Service_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    Service = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Category_Facilities_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    Facilities = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Enum_Category_Team_Display", ResourceType = typeof(ResQuestion))]
    Team = 3
}
```

And I need to set a chart color in the View based on the value of the Enum.

Now I do a switch in the View:

```
string color = "";
switch (answer.QuestionCategory)
{
    case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Overall: color = "#10c469"; break;
    case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Service: color = "#f9c851"; break;
    case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Facilities: color = "#188ae2"; break;
    case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Team: color = "#5b69bc"; break;
}
```

And I apply the color in the chart:

```
<round-progress max="5" current="@answer.Numeric" color="@color" semi="isSemi" rounded="rounded" clockwise="clockwise" responsive="responsive"></round-progress>
```

The problem is that I need the color based on the Enum's value in another View and I don't want to repeat the code (DRY).

Comment: please don't put this processing in views, it's untidy. And to resolve the reusability issue, create a helper method in your back-end so you can call it repeatedly and assign the processed value in to a model, and bind that view into that model

Comment: Hi thanks! But in your opinion, styling decisions should not be made in the Presentation Layer, in this case, the View?

Comment: Yes even if it's styling decisions, the values are still hardcoded and I can do it in my backend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an html helper as mxmissle mentioned in his answer. Another option is to create an extension method on the enum.

```
public static class QuestionCategoryExtensions
{
    public static string ToColor(this QuestionCategory category)
    {
            switch (category)
            {
                case QuestionCategory.Overall: return  "#10c469"; 
                case QuestionCategory.Service: return "#f9c851";
                case QuestionCategory.Facilities: return "#188ae2"; 
                case QuestionCategory.Team: return "#5b69bc"; 
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

and in your view, you can simply call this on the enum property of your model.

Assuming your view model has a property called Cat`enter code here`egory of type QuestionCategory enum

you can do like

```
@Model.Category.ToColor()
```

This extension method can be used in both views and controller code.

Comment: You can store it anywhere in your project.(Just create a new class and paste it). Just need to make sure that you are having the relevant `using` statement to import the namespace this class belongs to (Similar to how you access other classes)

Comment: Maybe with the public enum QuestionCategory namespace file

Comment: It is up to you where you want to keep it. I personally create a directory called "Extension methods" and keep my extension method classes there.

Comment: Thanks @Shyju! I have check your answer because it's working great and having the hability to extend the enum it's a great way for me to be able to join more information to each enum. Great solution!

Comment: Cool Glad i could help. mxmissile`s solution is also good. I use a mix of both as needed.

Comment: Yes, I have also comented this with him, if you would not put this answer, I would have choose his for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Create an HtmlHelper extension:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString QuestionCategoryColor(this HtmlHelper helper, QuestionCategory category)
    {
        string color = "";
        switch (category)
        {
            case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Overall: color = "#10c469"; break;
            case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Service: color = "#f9c851"; break;
            case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Facilities: color = "#188ae2"; break;
            case Core.Data.Models.QuestionCategory.Team: color = "#5b69bc"; break;
         }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(color);
    }
}
```

Then use in your views `@Html.QuestionCategoryColor(...)`

Comment: Hi thanks! I think your answer is great, and I would have use it for sure but the possibility to extend the enum of Shyju's is even better because I can use it everywhere in the project, and I know now how I can join more information to an enum. But thank you again.